# How to pass an array as a ref parameter

Tags: c#, vb.net

I appreciate some help translating the VB code below, to C#.
I am stuck in `obSMS.GetEstado(vMessages)`. I am invoking an external service that is supposed to retun me vMessages,
an array like the one described at the bottom. Each row of the array has 4 elements (0, 1 ,2 3).
Please I need a int in how to traslate obSMS.GetEstado(vMessages) to C#.

Thanks a lot

```
Dim obSMS As SMSEmpresarial.clsSMS
Dim vMessages As Object
Dim i As Integer

obSMS = New SMSEmpresarial.clsSMS
obSMS.GetEstado(vMessages)
For i = 0 To UBound(vMessages, 1) - 1
   Me.ListBox1.Items.Add("Cod:" & CStr(vMessages(i, 0)) &
   ":Tel:" & CStr(vMessages(i, 1)) & ":Est:" & CStr(vMessages(i, 2)) &
   ":Obs:" & CStr(vMessages(i, 3)))
Next
obSMS = Nothing
Exit Sub
```

How vMessages array looks like:

```
|row 0    |AAAAA   |BBBBB    |CCCCC   |DDDD
|row 1    |KKKKK   |PPPPP    |GGGGG   |HHHH
|row 2    |MMMMM   |FFFFF    |XXXXX   |ZZZZ
```

Comment: *obSMS.GetEstado(vMessages)* in C#: *obSMS.GetEstado(vMessages);*

Comment: vMessages is an object, so it's reference by default in C#

Comment: unless we're talking about double reference, but that's unlikely for a Get operation

Comment: @MatthewSainsbury That'll teach me not to skim... I suspect you're right

Comment: not really sure the question deserves any more than a skim... very low standard

Comment: He's declaring an object, then running some "Get" method that is somehow turning a regular `System.Object` into an array (what type? don't know) and then using late binding to not care about types. It's safe to say that he's passing the reference to the reference. So will need to use the ref keyword. There's definitely some bad code smell in all of this, though...

Comment: @Gusman: If the method 'GetEstado' creates the array and passes that back, then you need the 'ref' keyword. Don't understand how you're getting those points on your comment. See willaien's comment - it's the closest thing to an answer here.

Comment: If obSMS.GetEstado(vMessages) expects the param to be passed as ref, then when you write your code it will complain about the parameter being not pased as ref, if that's the case the just write *obSMS.GetEstado(ref vMessages);*, else the parameter is not passed by ref nor in vb or c#

Comment: Check my answer. It really has nothing to do with what in `vMessages` but rather, how you use it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope, this will answer first and last part of your question *"I appreciate some help translating the VB code below, to C#..."* ...*"Please I need a int in how to traslate obSMS.GetEstado(vMessages) to C#."*
http://converter.telerik.com/

```
SMSEmpresarial.clsSMS obSMS = default(SMSEmpresarial.clsSMS);
object vMessages = null;
int i = 0;

obSMS = new SMSEmpresarial.clsSMS();
obSMS.GetEstado(vMessages);
for (i = 0; i <= Information.UBound(vMessages, 1) - 1; i++) 
{
    this.ListBox1.Items.Add("Cod:" + Convert.ToString(vMessages(i, 0)) + ":Tel:" + Convert.ToString(vMessages(i, 1)) + ":Est:" + Convert.ToString(vMessages(i, 2)) + ":Obs:" + Convert.ToString(vMessages(i, 3)));
}
obSMS = null;
return;

//=======================================================
//Service provided by Telerik (www.telerik.com)
//Conversion powered by NRefactory.
//Twitter: @telerik
//Facebook: facebook.com/telerik
//=======================================================
```

Second part,

```
obSMS.GetEstado(vMessages);
```

Since  `vMessages` is object, you need to have it initialized if `obSMS.GetEstado(ref p)`.  If `obSMS.GetEstado(out p)`, you don't need to init your `vMessages`. But you need to call using one of those keywords - `obSMS.GetEstado(out vMessages)`

Comment: This doesn't deal with the op's main issue - the call to 'GetEstado' - there simply isn't enough information in the posted code to solve it via code conversion. We need information about the function 'GetEstado'.

Comment: Thanks a lot T.S. It worked like a charm! Best regards

Answer (score 1):

This should be a direct translation of your code. To make this more than just "give me the answer" bit, I will go ahead and explain what's going on in the translation. Here's the code first:

```
//Declaring and initializing obSMS. var keyword uses implicit typing.
var obSMS = new SMSEmpresarial.clsSMS();

//Declaring this as dynamic, because I have no clue what the eventual type will be.
dynamic vMessages = new object();
obSMS.GetEstado(ref vMessages);

foreach(var message in vMessages)
{
    //this replaces Me
    //+ is used to concatenate instead of &
    //[] is the index accessor in C#
    //ToString() is called instead of CStr()
    this.ListBox1.Items.Add("Cod:" + vMessages[0].ToString() + ":Tel:" + vMessages[1].ToString() + ":Est:" + vMessages[2].ToString() + ":Obs:" + vMessages[3].ToString());
}
```

The biggest issue is that we don't know what `vMessages` is changed to, so I'm using latebinding via the `dynamic` keyword. Late binding in .net when you're not interfacing with Com or something dynamic is generally considered bad practice...